# SELECT * FROM a subquery which beings with IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can't seem to figure this out.

The table `OrganizationUserSettings` has two rows where `SettingSys` is `3` and `OrganizationSys` is `1012`.

There will *always* be a row where `OrgUserSettingsProfileSys` is null.  There *might* be a row (or many rows) where it has a value.

Given a parameter `@OrgUserSettingsProfileSys`, I need a row that matches if it exists.  If there isn't one, then I need the row where it's null.

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    IF EXISTS (Select * FROM OrganizationUserSettings WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM OrganizationUserSettings WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM OrganizationUserSettings WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys IS NULL
    END
)
WHERE SettingSys = 3 AND OrganizationSys = 1012
```

With this, I get

> Incorrect syntax near 'IF'

**EDIT:**

I've simplified this query for the sake of posting here. I need this to be part of a subquery.

Comment: you could just `Select Top 1 Order by OrgUserSettingsProfileSys desc`

Comment: @JamieD77, that won't work.  There could be many rows where `OrgUserSettingsProfileSys` has a value.

Comment: `where OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys or OrgUserSettingsProfileSys is NULL` ?

Comment: yeah but how many of those rows have `WHERE SettingSys = 3 AND OrganizationSys = 1012`

Comment: @JamieD77, possibly many

Comment: If you want all of the rows where `OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys` you can use Gordon's second suggestion and include `With Ties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT top 1 * 
FROM OrganizationUserSettings 
WHERE SettingSys = 3 AND OrganizationSys = 1012
and (OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys or OrgUserSettingsProfileSys is NULL)
order by OrgUserSettingsProfileSys desc
```

Comment: This will not return the expected results if there are multiple rows with the same OrgUserSettingsProfileSys value.

Comment: OP doesnt look to be particular about that or that scenario is ok with him. I do like the WITH TIES solution though, good to know

Comment: I agree. WITH TIES solution worked in the example that I was testing with.

Answer (score 3):

you can use top 1 with ties to get more than one row if there are multiple rows that are not null

```
select      top 1 with ties
            *
from        OrganizationUserSettings
where       SettingSys = 3
and         OrganizationSys = 1012
and         (   OrgUserSettingsProfileSys is null
          or    OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys)
order by    case
                when OrgUserSettingsProfileSys is null then 2
            else 1
            end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to have to go Google `with ties`.  This is new to me.

Comment: Good to know ! (With Ties)

Comment: This is such an elegant solution when you have multiple rows with the same OrgUserSettingsProfileSys value

Answer (score 2):

You can't put an `IF` inside a query like this.

One way you can do what you seem to be trying to do is this way:

```
IF EXISTS(SomeQuery)
   SELECT Query A
ELSE
   SELECT Query B
```

A way to make a subquery that does what you seem to want to do is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeColumn IS NOT NULL AND OtherConditions
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM MyTable 
  WHERE SomeColumn IS NULL AND OtherConditions
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeColumn IS NOT NULL AND OtherConditions)
) sq
```

Comment: Edited my answer.   You simplified your example query so much that I'm having to do a bit of guessing at your intent.

Comment: yeah I should have included that in the first place.  Sorry!  And thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird query.  Perhaps you intend:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT *
      FROM OrganizationUserSettings
      WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys
     )
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT t.*
       FROM t
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT *
       FROM OrganizationUserSettings
       WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys IS NULL AND
             NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t)
      )
     ) t
WHERE SettingSys = 3 AND OrganizationSys = 1012;
```

If you are expecting only one row to match, then this is more simply written as:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT TOP (1) *
      FROM OrganizationUserSettings
      WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys OR
            OrgUserSettingsProfileSys IS NULL
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN OrgUserSettingsProfileSys IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE SettingSys = 3 AND OrganizationSys = 1012;
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
   IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrganizationUserSettings
    WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys
)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM OrganizationUserSettings
        WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys
    ) AS x
    WHERE SettingSys = 3
          AND OrganizationSys = 1012;

END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM OrganizationUserSettings
        WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys IS NULL
    ) AS x
    WHERE SettingSys = 3
          AND OrganizationSys = 1012;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `OR` should work, either checking, that the value exists and the row has the value or, that the value doesn't exist and the row has a null value.

```
SELECT *
       FROM OrganizationUserSettings
       WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM OrganizationUserSettings
                             WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys)
              AND OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys
               OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM OrganizationUserSettings
                                     WHERE OrgUserSettingsProfileSys = @OrgUserSettingsProfileSys)
                  AND OrgUserSettingsProfileSys IS NULL)
             AND SettingSys = 3
             AND OrganizationSys = 1012;
```